# Help Needed to Identify/Source Varistor S14 K140 0023

Tags: identification, circuit-protection, varistor

Could someone please advise on how I interprate the codes on this Varistor below..
I'm almost there, I can find the S14 / K140 on RS Components, But im unsure about the last 4 digits.
[RS Website PN:2508485459](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/2508485459/) 
The part I have is numbered 0023  Im unsure what this stands for. I have heard that it may be the manufacturing date, in which case the one I have found will be the correct item. I just want to be sure it isnt another rating variable of some kind.

The Varistor is from a 110v Honeywell DKO 972 Flame Control unit from an EOGB X500 oil Burner.

Could someone just give me the nod as to if I have found the correct part and that I only need the **S14 K140** part of the code.  Thanks in advance.  Roy

[image: S14 K140]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one from EPCOS: -

[image]

It's an S14K140 and it has the extra codes as 0345 and that means it was made in the 45th week of 2003. Does that convince you? Here's one made in 1998: -

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Andy aka I know i'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 0):

S14 means the disk diameter 14mm
K140 means the operating voltage 140 VAC

so a S20K275 is a 20mm disk with an operating voltage of 275 VAC

Always overate a varistor voltage by 20%

the disk goes up with its max pulse power